# excluding .exe file (referenced by my app)

Tags: c#

salam guyz! 
i make a project and i referenced a .exe file into its bin folder, now in a button click event i want to exclude/extract/copy that .exe file into a different path on my computer.(i am trying this while i have installed my app)

in c#

Comment: try to explain again, you want to copy an EXE that you put in the project's references?

Comment: Is this what you're after? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)

Comment: Silly markdown, breaks urls with parens. Silly SO, forbidding a third edit. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28computing%29

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure the exe is copied to the bin folder, by selecting the reference you added to the project, properties, `copy local = true`.

Then, to retrieve the path of the 'other' exe at runtime and copy/move it, you can do the following:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

// ...

FileInfo appMainExe = new FileInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
string appFolder = appMainExe.DirectoryName;
string theOtherExe = Path.Combine(appFolder, "my_exe_file.exe");
File.Copy(theOtherExe, "a_new_full_path");  // or File.Move
```